# use date from fetch object to create link for fetch another object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I write some code and works but i think maybe can be done on some better way. What i want from code? I create link and fetch object from that object i want use some value and pass that value in another link after that fetch new object. My code working but i want see if is possible new solution.

```
const [key, setKey] = useState("");
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => { 
    getKey();
    getWeather();
},[key]);
```

//this function get key from object and that key i will use in another link

```
const getKey = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

        (position) => {
            const long = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
            const lat = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);

            const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
            const link = `${proxy}http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=rhlYEhvAu0nhFNMFybOIhffbmjFX0AZN&q=${lat}%2C${long}&details=true`;

            (async function fetchData(){
                const getValue = await fetch (link);
                const key = await getValue.json();
                setKey(key.Key);
            })();
        }
     );
};

const getWeather = async () => {
    const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
    const link = `${proxy}http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${key}?apikey=rhlYEhvAu0nhFNMFybOIhffbmjFX0AZN&details=true&metric=true`;
    const data = await fetch (link);
    const getData = await data.json();
    setData(getData);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work by just making a few slight changes to your code. Make the `useEffect` and `async` function, return the key from `getKey` to a variable and await the variable assignment and pass to `getWeather`. Something like this:

```
const [key, setKey] = useState("");
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(async() => { // <---- Converted to async
    const apiKey = getKey(); // <---- Assigned to variable
    getWeather(await apiKey); // <--- Using apiKey in function rather than just state
},[key]);

const getKey = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

        (position) => {
            const long = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
            const lat = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);

            const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
            const link = `${proxy}http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=rhlYEhvAu0nhFNMFybOIhffbmjFX0AZN&q=${lat}%2C${long}&details=true`;

            (async function fetchData(){
                const getValue = await fetch (link);
                const key = await getValue.json();
                setKey(key.Key);
                return key.Key     //<------ returned key for useEffect
            })();
        }
     );
};

const getWeather = async (apiKey = key) => { // <----If no value passed to function, will use state value
    const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
    const link = `${proxy}http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${apiKey}?apikey=rhlYEhvAu0nhFNMFybOIhffbmjFX0AZN&details=true&metric=true`;
    const data = await fetch (link);
    const getData = await data.json();
    setData(getData);
};
```

The reason I returned the value rather than using state is because setting state is asynchronous and there is currently no callback function for the `useState` setting function like there was for `setState`.

Comment: thanks man i will try this...I have one more question...after fetch object i cant get all value for example  const key = await getValue.json(); i must put key.Key and set state in that function outside i cant get Key value, only after call from state...What if i have object and he have group object...how get value of individually property of that object...or i must setState for every object inside that object???

Comment: I'm not really following your question.

I think you're saying that key.Key doesn't always have a value? If so, try destructuring and awaiting the value like this:

const {Key} = await key;
setKey(Key);
return Key

If I'm misunderstanding your question, please try to rephrase.